TLinkLabel in Delphi does not work properly
I want to use a TLinkLabel in Delphi. But it seems that it does not work properly. It neither shows the link nor reacts while clicking on it.
I did the following:
LinkLabel1.Caption :=
    'Click <a href=''https://duckduckgo.com/''>here</a> in order to open the search engine.';

But it still displays the whole HTML content. It should replace the <a href=.... The LinkLabel1LinkClick routine is also not called.
What have I done wrong?

Those should probably be actual "s, not single quotes?

TLinkLabel does not accept single quotes (') surrounding the link. It needs double quotes (").
LinkLabel1.Caption :=
  'Click <a href="https://duckduckgo.com/">here</a> in order to open the search engine.';

